# Vim: Changing pattern if nothing found?

Tags: vim

If I ran a search pattern and nothing was found, is there a shortcut to bring it back for me to edit?

Comment: You can also use <C-p>, <C-n> instead of arrows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typing the character for the appropriate mode (`/` or `:`) and pushing the up arrow will recall previous commands of that type.

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>/</kbd> and then <kbd>↑</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

The last search pattern is also saved in the `/` register.  If you want to use it in another command (such as `:s/...`) then you can insert it in the command line with `<CTRL-R>\`.